# What is an easy but reliable way to parse parameters in C?

Tags: c, parsing

I have some input parameters like:

> **param1**=*param1Value*&**param2**=*param2Value*&**param3**=*param3Value*...

These parameters are linked with the character '**&**', the parameter and its value is linked with '**=**'. I want to parse them into a key-value-map like this:

```
[param1, param1Value], [param2, param2Value], [param3, param3Value],...
```

But because the parameter's value contains the tow *key-characters*, this would break the parameter-parsing procedure.

I was informed the parameter passer, who created these parameter format to easy customize, such as changing the parameter value for different application using *sprintf*. So its hard to persuade them to separator these parameters in a map-array.

I was originally going to use yacc/lex, but is to complicated to such a *little-feature*. [*sscanf*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827714/whats-the-easiest-way-to-parse-a-string-in-c) can also parse text something like regexp, but it does not seem so easy to build a regexp-like string for my parameter-list.

Is there any simple but reliable way to parse them without key-character?

Comment: What do you mean if a value contains the key character? You mean that the values can have `&` or `=` in them? And they're not escaped?

Comment: That look likes an HTTP request string. Why don't you use one of the libraries intended for those?

Comment: Yes, the key-character can also include in the value string. If they are escaped like `\&` or `\=`, what if the real value is `\=`?

Comment: to @cha0site, I do want to use lib to release myself, but...there is no such lib I can adop, even the HTTP client isn't available, so I coded it, include SSL, XAuth...

Comment: if the real value is `\=` you write `\\=` and of course you need to escape the escape char too!

Comment: have you ever heard about cURL? (talking about HTTP client)

Comment: If it was a HTTP request, the problem wouldn't exist, because those characters would be encoded as `%26` and `%3D` respectively! So it's definitely something else.

Comment: Yes, I have fixed them: while passer give me the parameters, they should use `\\` to escape the `=` and `&`, but the `\\` itself do not need to escape. While I extracted these parameters, I just replace the  `\&` with `&`, and `\=` with '='. If the real value is `\\=`, just encoded it with `\\\&`, I do not need to analyse the `\` character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`strtok`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) to tokenize the string at the `'&'` character, then split the "tokens" at `'='` to get the parameter names and values.

The splitting at `'='` can either be done with `strtok` as well (or rather `strtok_r`) or using [`strchr`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr) and [`strncpy`/`strcpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) or [`strndup`/`strdup`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup).

Answer (score 0):

If you are guaranteed that pattern you could use a simple parse function.

If you are guaranteed a max length of key/value then fixed buffer + copy would be the simplest. Else you could first find location of separator, then malloc that size, etc.

As a simple ***example***/concept with fixed size of max 100 i.e.:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_pair(char **p, char *key, char *val)
{
    int esc = 0;    /* escape level */
    char *cp = key; /* current target */

    *key = '\0';    /* if either is blank */
    *val = '\0';

    if (!*p || !**p)
        return 0;

    /* this could be done more elegant */
    while (**p) {
        if (**p == '=' && (esc & 1) == 0) {
            *cp = '\0'; /* terminate */
            cp = val;   /* change target */
            ++(*p);
            continue;
        } else if (**p == '&' && (esc & 1) == 0) {
            ++(*p);     /* skip & and break */
            break;
        }

        if (**p == '\\') {
            if((++esc & 1) == 0) /* if 2, 4, 6 ... \'s */
                *cp++ = **p;
        } else {
            esc = 0;
            *cp++ = **p;
        }
        ++(*p);
    }

    *cp = '\0';
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *data = "ab=123&a\\=42&m\\\\ed\\=\\&do\\\\\\\\=mix";
    char key[100];
    char val[100];

    printf("Parse: %s\n", data);

    while (get_pair(&data, key, val))
        printf("key: %s\nval: %s\n\n", key, val);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Output:

```
Parse: ab=123&a\=42&m\\ed\=\&do\\\\=mix
key: ab
val: 123

key: a=42
val: 

key: m\ed=&do\\
val: mix
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have fixed them: while passer give me the parameters, they should use `\` to escape the `=` and `&`, but the `\` itself do not need to escape. While I extracted these parameters, I just replace the  `\&` with `&`, and `\=` with '='. If the real value is `\\=`, just encoded it with `\\\=`. I do not need to analyse the `\` character, just leave them where they are.